# use the sensor accelerometer and mp3 player

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I would create a small app that uses the accelerometer sensor to start the mp3 player. Basically my idea is this:
1) start the application
2) Turn off the screen of your smartphone
3) shake the cell
4) start the mp3 player, with a song by default

I'm not expert in programming in Android, I hope in your help

Answer (score 0):

Look at my sample for shaking device at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9975422/779408)

For mediaPlayer:

```
public static void playMusic(Context context, int beepType) {
        try { 

            mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.mymusic);

            mMediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
            mMediaPlayer.start();
            mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new
                    OnCompletionListener() {
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                            // if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
                            // mMediaPlayer.release();
                            // mMediaPlayer = null;
                            // }
                        }
                    });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
                mMediaPlayer.release();
                mMediaPlayer = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you check this out  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36643083/can-anyone-tell-me-how-do-i-start-mp3