# can anyone tell me how do I start mp3?

Tags: android, android-alarms

I am making a project ,I need to start mp3 or any loud sound automatically when the toast "Fall Detected" appears for 20 second.

```
 public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) 
 {
     if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) 
     {
         long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
         if ((curTime - mLastShakeTime) > MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_SHAKES_MILLISECS) 
         {
             float x = event.values[0];
             float y = event.values[1];
             float z = event.values[2];

             double acceleration = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2) + Math.pow(z, 2)) - SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;

             Log.d("mySensor", "Acceleration is " + acceleration + "m/s^2");

             if (acceleration < -9.00f && acceleration> -15.00f ) 
             {
                 mLastShakeTime = curTime;
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FALL DETECTED",
                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Given the context you might need to be a bit clearer about what you mean by "alarm".  In Android `Alarm` refers specifically to a method to cause the application to wake up at a specific time in the future.  Is this what you want, or are you after a "make some noise" alarm?

Comment: yes you got right , i am using alarm to waking up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your clarifications to the original question it sounds like you want to play a sound.  In which case you want something like:

```
final MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.alarm);
player.start();
```

`R.raw.alarm` is the resource for the file containing the sound you want to play.

Comment: can you tell me how do i make the sound loud without user state of change, i mean whenever mobile is silent or not the sound have to play loud.

Comment: Please start another question for this, as it is a different issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is the link to set the alarm http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/Scheduler.zip call the setAlarm(context) method after you show your toast

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)

Hope this help , be care of the TYPE.